# Create sql function properly to return table

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

everyone

I have some trouble with creation of my fucntion.
Here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customers_rental_activity (IN i_client_id 
BIGINT DEFAULT NULL)                                            
RETURNS TABLE(metric_name TEXT, metric_value TEXT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
SELECT 'customer''s info#' AS "name", first_name || ', ' || last_name || 
', ' || email AS "value" 
FROM customer c
WHERE customer_id = i_client_id
END; 
$$
```

But something goes wrong on the step of creation.
Could you show show how to make this function work??

```
select get_customers_rental_activity(60);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us what goes wrong. What error message appears?   And, often it's smart to get your query working first, then embed it in stored code.

Comment: Ok, when I try to execute it I have errors SQL Error [42601]: --- "SELECT")¶  Position: 219

Comment: I did it
try using the correct query syntax from this page
thanks to all!

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-returns-a-table/

Comment: Language is sql, not plpgsql.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how does your table customers looks like so I can't tell whether this select is correct or not, but your code has some other weak points. First of all you forgot `BEGIN` word after the `AS $$`. Then you didn't put any `RETURN` statement. This is how it should look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customers_rental_activity (
    IN i_client_id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL
)    
    
RETURNS TABLE (
    metric_name TEXT,
    metric_value TEXT
)
    
AS $$
BEGIN
    
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT 'customer''s info#' AS "name", first_name || ', ' || last_name || ', ' || email AS "value"
        FROM customer c
        WHERE customer_id = i_client_id;

END; 
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```